# Was bitcoin peer to peer network affected because of the recent BGP hijack incident?

Tags: bitcoin-core, network, full-node, p2p

Can someone ELI5 BGP hijacking, impact on Bitcoin, countermeasures and if there were any issues because of the recent incident?

Related links: https://twitter.com/ProtonMail/status/1311013829514539011

https://twitter.com/troyhunt/status/1311792730046033920

https://hackingdistributed.com/2017/05/01/bgp-attacks-on-btc/

https://www.wired.com/2014/08/isp-bitcoin-theft/

Related question: [Could the BGP attack be used to split the Bitcoin network?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/29912/could-the-bgp-attack-be-used-to-split-the-bitcoin-network)