# In what ways does BGP hijacking affect Bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin-core, security, privacy

Based on this [answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/30305/133407) from 2014, bitcoin nodes are vulnerable to BGP hijacking although I am looking for more details about how BGP hijacking attack could affect Bitcoin p2p network.

What could be helpful?

- Research articles or paper describing attacks, analysis of bitcoin nodes and their networks
- Best practices for a user and and exchange using bitcoin node

Lot of cryptocurrency services have been attacked recently and last attack affected AWS IP addresses.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a summary of some recent events and the only question I can see is “Has someone else written about this?”.

Comment: @Murch I had tried writing short question in https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/114795/encryption-for-mempool-privacy and you expected a summary. This question is closed because it has summary with a question. There are lot of questions in which someone asked for research articles or papers: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=research

Comment: And its surely not offtopic

Comment: I didn't say it's off-topic, I am pointing out that it's unclear what the scope of your interest is, and what sort of answer would satisfy your query. Your question post does not pose a practical, answerable question that inspires answers that explain “why” and “how”. Further you seem to expect that a potential responder read one or several links to find out what you're interested in. If there is a question in there, you may want to rephrase it more explicitly such as “How could BGP attacks be used to attack Bitcoin?”, “How could one defend Bitcoin against BGP attacks?” or whatever your Q is.

Comment: Offtopic is mentioned on top: https://i.imgur.com/YakOgNo.png and question is **Has any bitcoin developer written a detailed blog post or research article like nusenu?** which was opened 5 months ago and edited yesterday with a relevant link. It can be rephrased in several ways and there wasn't any need to close it. One of the ways to rephrase: "I am looking for a research article or paper which describes the impact of BGP hijacking in bitcoin p2p network and best practices"

Comment: I do not expect people to read all the links and its one of the reasons I shared summary, my research and a graph. I can remove everything if that helps people to answer this question in a better way.

Comment: I agree here; I don't think there is much to say here apart from "apparently not". If you'd reformulate your question as "In what ways does BGP hijacting affect Bitcoin?", or something more specific, I think there'd be a lot more to say.

Comment: Question is edited with exact thing shared by @PieterWuille in title, removing all links, graph, my research etc. and rephrasing the body of question.